# Why might the server not receive a certificate attached to a request using HttpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate, dotnet-httpclient, x509certificate2

We're trying to connect to an endpoint that does nothing more than verify whether a certificate has been correctly attached.

Our code is straightforward:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler())
{
    var rawcert = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\OpenSSL\bin\cert.pem");
    var rawkey = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\OpenSSL\bin\private.key");

    var provider = new CertificateFromFileProvider(rawcert, rawkey);
    var certificate = provider.Certificate;

    handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
    handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback +=
    (HttpRequestMessage req, X509Certificate2 cert2, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors err) =>
    {
        Trace.WriteLine($"Sender: {req}");
        Trace.WriteLine($"cert: {cert2}");
        Trace.WriteLine($"chain: {chain}");
        Trace.WriteLine($"sslPolicyErrors: {err}");
        return true;
    };

    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        var response = await client.GetStringAsync("https://{uri}/mtlsTest");
        return response;
    }
}
```

(This is a sandbox environment for a proof of concept, so we're comfortable shortcutting the ValidationCallback for now.)

We can see the certificate is attached appears well-formed in the callback (origin and subject are as-expected), but we're getting a response from the server that indicates no certificate was attached. Why might that be?

We have also tried exporting the certificate as a `pfx` and attaching that instead of the original `pem` file, with an identical result.

**Update**

Thanks to useful comments below from @bartonjs and @Crypt32, we've tried adding the private key (using the handy [Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenSSL.X509Certificate2.Provider) from @stef-heyenrath), but although this results in the certificate that we add to the handler showing `HasPrivateKey=true`:

[image]

... when the ValidationCallback fires, the `X509Certificate2` traces `HasPrivateKey=false`:

[image]

... and we get the same error as before - the server never acknowledges receiving the certificate.

If we package the `.pem` and the private key into a `.pfx` using open ssl:
`pkcs12 -inkey private.key -in cert.pem -export -out cert.pfx`
... then we get the same result again, and the server can find no certificate. Likewise if we install the certificate in the personal store and load it from there (same result). An inspection with Wireshark suggests the certificate is simply never being attached.

Why would this be? Full revised code above.

Comment: Are you certain that the server is requesting that the client provide a client certificate?

Comment: Yes. The entire function of that endpoint is that it test a MTLS implementation by echoing the content of an attached certificate (or, as in this case, echoing that no certificate was found).

Comment: The client cert needs to have a private key (HasPrivateKey=true) to work, at minimum.

Comment: The certificate you are importing into `X509Certificate2` object doesn't contain private key, as the result, this certificate cannot be used for client authentication.

Comment: Thanks @bartonjs - see update above.

Comment: Thanks @Crypt32 - see update above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial problem here was a badly-formed certificate provided by our test host.

A further problem (once we had a good certificate to work with) was with the output of the `CertificateFromFileProvider` method of the `OpenSSL.X509Certificate2Provider` NuGet package.

For whatever reason, the certificate created would not work correctly. Taking the same input files and generating a `.pfx` with [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) resulted in an `X509Certificate2` that worked fine.